# NumberFormatException, Invalid long

Tags: android, long-integer, numberformatexception

In my app, I pass a certain value (in this case "p500108270") via an intent to the other activity.

The second activity makes it a long with Long.parseLong(string).

When I compile now I get a NumberFormatException saying that the Long is not valid.

What can I do against this? I need to have this first letter and I need to use long.

Thanks

Comment: How is it that you need a long if you have a character in there? Take it out before parsing and add it back in to whatever afterwards

Comment: I'm working with the Jamendo API with Retrofit and as an ID it doesn't accept Strings, whyever.. How could I add it after parsing?

Comment: Never used that api but I guess you can't add it in if it only allows a long. I didn't know what you were trying to do. Still unsure but I guess you would need to store the p as a string somewhere not in the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add a p in the URL in the Retrofit answer before (id) (what they call URL manipulation, check out the Retrofit site to find out more about that) where the id long was given.

Thanks for the help ideas though!

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a `String` between the activities (p500108270) and then, where you need, parse only the numerical part of the String to a `long`. For example:

```
long num = Long.parseLong(passedString.substring(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

try getting rid of the character just for this part
Long.parseLong(string.substring(1));